# How can I replace <background android:drawable="@color/ic_meter_launcher_background"/> with a value in Android Studio?

Tags: android

Code A is generated automatically by Android Studio.

I hope to replace  `<background android:drawable="@color/ic_meter_launcher_background"/>` with a color value, but both Code B and Code C are wrong.

How can I do?

**Code A**

> **ic_launcher.xml file**
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>     <background android:drawable="@color/ic_meter_launcher_background"/>
>     <foreground android:drawable="@drawable/ic_meter_launcher_foreground"/>
> </adaptive-icon>
> ```
>
> **ic_meter_launcher_background.xml file**
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <resources>
>     <color name="ic_meter_launcher_background">#3DDC84</color>
> </resources>
> ```

**Code B**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@color/#3DDC84"/>
    <foreground android:drawable="@drawable/ic_meter_launcher_foreground"/>
</adaptive-icon>
```

**Code C**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="#3DDC84"/>
    <foreground android:drawable="@drawable/ic_meter_launcher_foreground"/>
</adaptive-icon>
```

Comment: Look at this line in **Code B** ``<background android:drawable="@color/#3DDC84"/>`` **@color/#3DDC84** i think it need to change like this **#3DDC84**

Comment: Thanks! But Code C is wrong.

Comment: Didn't test it out, but try to `tools:override="true"` to that resource

Comment: It seems your only choice is to use the color resources as shown in example A. Can you elaborate on what is wrong with the approach in example A?

Comment: Can you specify on what kind of error you are facing with the code snippets ? Or do you mean you do not see the background changed with Code B and C ? @HelloCW

Answer (score 0):

You can override any resource of the Android app and even the framework itself:

`<color tools:override="true" name="ic_meter_launcher_background">#3DDC84</color>`

where `tools` should be a `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` in your resources XML file header.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

> ic_launcher.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@drawable/ic_meter_launcher_background"/>
    <foreground android:drawable="@drawable/ic_meter_launcher_foreground"/>
</adaptive-icon>
```

> ic_meter_launcher_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="108dp"
    android:height="108dp"
    android:viewportWidth="108"
    android:viewportHeight="108">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#3F3F4A"
        android:pathData="M0,0h108v108h-108z" />
</vector>
```